# JavaScript без HTML и CSS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Хочу начать учить JavaScript для бэкенда (node.js). Вопрос: можно ли начать учить без знаний HTML & CSS? Смогу ли я применить на стадии обучения JavaScript без HTML & CSS?
UPD: Хочу писать приложения под десктоп, и возможно, под Android & iOS.

Comment: можно начать учить

Comment: Можно, но скучно и неинтересно, к тому же наверняка вам их сразу засунут в уроки. Изучить HTML и CSS на простейшем уровне достаточно быстро, вы же не профессиональные сайты сразу клепать собрались.

Comment: https://www.codingame.com/  Интересный ресурс. Выбираете язык какой хотите применить и решаете задачки разного рода по разным направлениям.

Comment: @AlexKrass, почему неинтересно?

Comment: @Qwertiy, придется работать из консоли все время и никакого особого интерактива. Все-таки это может быть намного скучнее, чем иметь в распоряжении хоть какой-то функционал - кнопочки там к примеру.

Comment: @AlexKrass, ну консольные проги тоже бывает интересно писать, а интерактив с кнопочками можно в телеграм-боте утроить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу начать учить JavaScript для бэкенда (node.js). Вопрос: можно ли начать учить без знаний HTML & CSS?

Конечно, это самостоятельные языки. Просто не надо изучать работу с DOM'ом и глобальные браузерные сущности, а вместо них посмотреть на стандартные модули nodejs. Ну и вместо подключения скриптов к странице смотреть систему модулей.

> Смогу ли я применить на стадии обучения JavaScript без HTML & CSS?

Для BE - да. Например, какие-то серверы api или боты для телеграма, контакта. Ну и всякие вычислительные задачи (хотя для nodejs это крайне сомнительное применение в силу однопоточности), обработка файлов и всё, что можно упихать в консольное приложение - это само собой.

> Хочу писать приложения под десктоп

А вот тут косяк. Сама по себе нода не предоставляет ничего для графического интерфейса. Наиболее популярен [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), который позволяет писать кроссплатформенные приложения на ноде, но в качестве UI выступает окно со встроенным в него браузером (хромом или хромиумом - не уверен), соответственно разработчик пишет на html+css+js. Таким образом написаны Slack, Skype и Telegram (если не ошибаюсь).

> и возможно, под Android & iOS.

В принципе тут помимо электрона появляется ещё несколько фреймвёрков. Но наиболее популярные кроме react native - это снова html. React native со своим jsx тоже похож на html, но на самом деле строится из нативных компонентов, поэтому может оказаться, что знания html и css будут не очень-то и нужны. Хотя я на нём не писал и гарантировать не могу.

Comment: Сильно. Спасибо, что даете ответ на вопрос, на который "невозможно дать объективный и однозначный ответ".  Только вот именно ответы на такие вопросы хочется читать.